# winforms SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition

we have started to play about with the speechRecognitionEngine, and built a very basic app based on one that we found on stack overflow. Code below:-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sr = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Create an in-process speech recognizer for the en-US locale.

    }

    private void BeginSpeach()
    {
        //Create grammar
        Choices words = new Choices();
        words.Add("Hi");
        words.Add("No");
        words.Add("Yes");

        Grammar wordsList = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(words));

        wordsList.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec_SpeechRecognized);
        sr.LoadGrammar(wordsList);

        sr.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sr.RecognizeAsync();
    }


    void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, RecognitionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginSpeach();
    }
}
```

This seems to work great. The only issue is that once it has detected the word "hi", thats is, it won't defect any more.
Is there a way to get this to always listen? so i can say "hi", then "no", then "yes".

We hope to build on this to create a list of commands

Thank you for any advice

Comment: It happens the same with RecognizeCompleted event?

Comment: this pointed me to the answer which I've posted the code below, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Came to the conclusion from tweellt.

```
sr.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(rec_test);
```

and then calling this again

```
 private void rec_test(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        sr.RecognizeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thats it! Another thing you might find useful is to use SpeechHypothesized event. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could just change

```
sr.RecognizeAsync();
```

in `BeginSpeach()` to

```
sr.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

This will detect everything you say...

### [Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx)

**RecognizeAsync()** - Performs a single, asynchronous speech recognition operation.

**RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode)** - Performs one or more asynchronous speech recognition operations.