# Speech SDK - LoadGrammar() raising UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows-8, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Speech Recognition lib on C# (4.5) on my Windows 8.

I installed "Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11" and I'm receiving an exception using LoadGrammar.

My program:

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpeechRecognition
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an in-process speech recognizer for the en-US locale.
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
            {
                // Create and load a dictation grammar.
                // An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

                recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized += 
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

                // Configure input to the speech recognizer.
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                // Keep the console window open.
                while (true)
                {
                  Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

        // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
        static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

Stack Trace:

> em
>   System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.Initialize(SapiRecognizer
>   recognizer, Boolean inproc)    em
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.get_RecoBase()    em
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(Grammar
>   grammar)    em SpeechRecognition.Program.Main(String[] args) na
>   e:\TestCenter\SpeechRecognition\SpeechRecognition\Program.cs:linha 23 
>   em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    em
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    em
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    em
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

I tested in Win7 and Win8, but no one is working.

Can anybody give-me some help?

Comment: That's not the code causing your problem. It's not possible to get that error from it.

Comment: I think you forgot to use these 2 lines at the beginning of your file: `using System;` and `using System.Speech.Recognition;`

Comment: @AndrewBarber it really is. This is the first line of my code.

Comment: @Oliboy50 actually I'm using (using System; using  System.Speech.Recognition; using System.Speech.Synthesis;). =/

Comment: @Crasher It may be the first line, but it's not possible to be the line causing that error.

Comment: @Oliboy50 If Crasher was missing `using` declarations, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Crasher have you tried to just copy/paste this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms554259%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm trying to use "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture" but I'm getting the same error. I don´t use constructor and I don´t initialize any var outside Main (I'm using Console Application). Thanks for your help man =)

Comment: @Oliboy50 it crashes on "using" statement oO

Comment: Crashier how about either showing all relevant code.. or show the code where the error is actually being thrown.and we can't see any `using statement`

Comment: You've included no `using` statement here, in your code. As I've noted multiple times, the code you have posted *cannot* generate the error you have posted. It's not possible. The error is occurring elsewhere.

Comment: RE: Your updated question; Nope. Still not there. That's basically the exact same code. If that's the *exact line* that you are being told the error is on, you have your code compiled with optimizations.

Comment: @DJKRAZE it works if I remove that overload on RecognitionEngine. But I get this error when I try to use "LoadGrammar(..)" - "An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Speech.dll"

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm using in Debug mode now, and I cleaned my solution.. if I remove that overload in RecognitionEngine the problem is gone. But then it appears again when I try to use "LoadGrammar(...)"

Comment: Crasher.. let me make life a little bit easier for you..
post all code where you are getting the error we do not know what your LoadGrammar() method looks like

Comment: @Crasher What "overload in RecognitionEngine"?

Comment: take a look at this post.. also read `SO` documentation on how to formulate as wel as ask a question.. there are so many examples on the net about how to do this as well .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332157/winforms-speechrecognitionengine

Comment: @AndrewBarber I included all my code (copied from MSDN) =)

Comment: That's better; Just to be sure: This exception is different. Is that the exception you get with that code? Also, do you have the stack trace?

Comment: I would expect to see something like this as well 
`DictationGrammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation");
dictationGrammar.Name = "DictationQuestion";
recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); 
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();`
how is this object defined in regards to the elements of this object 
`recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());`

Comment: @DJKRAZE the same =/ ...I included the stack trace to. Thanks for your help man! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely I seem to recall having similar problems with the Speech SDK, but can't find the solution. I think it involved something like changing the owner or access rights to some file or folder on your machine. Maybe some more googlebinging could help you find the solution I found back then or maybe you could use ProcessMonitor to see what the process is trying to do and failing. Maybe eventvwr would show something.

I tried installing the Speech Platform SDK 11 and the Speech Platform Runtime, but I think these might be a server version of the technology that uses the `Microsoft.Speech` namespace in its .NET wrapper. I also installed Speech SDK 5.3, but I think that's not the latest version. Ultimately I ended up installing [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) and I think that did it for me. This works fine in my WPF app:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SpeechTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="tb"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Windows;

namespace SpeechTestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create a SpeechRecognitionEngine object for the default recognizer in the en-US locale.
            this.recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            {

                // Create a grammar for finding services in different cities.
                Choices services = new Choices(new string[] { "restaurants", "hotels", "gas stations" });
                Choices cities = new Choices(new string[] { "Seattle", "Boston", "Dallas" });

                GrammarBuilder findServices = new GrammarBuilder("Find");
                findServices.Append(services);
                findServices.Append("near");
                findServices.Append(cities);

                // Create a Grammar object from the GrammarBuilder and load it to the recognizer.
                Grammar servicesGrammar = new Grammar(findServices);
                recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(servicesGrammar);

                // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized += recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
                recognizer.SpeechDetected += RecognizerOnSpeechDetected;
                recognizer.SpeechHypothesized += RecognizerOnSpeechHypothesized;
                recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += RecognizerOnSpeechRecognitionRejected;
                recognizer.AudioStateChanged += RecognizerOnAudioStateChanged;
                recognizer.AudioSignalProblemOccurred += RecognizerOnAudioSignalProblemOccurred;

                // Configure the input to the speech recognizer.
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
        }

        private void RecognizerOnAudioSignalProblemOccurred(object sender, AudioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs audioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(audioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs.AudioSignalProblem.ToString());
        }

        private void RecognizerOnAudioStateChanged(object sender, AudioStateChangedEventArgs audioStateChangedEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(audioStateChangedEventArgs.AudioState.ToString());
        }

        private void RecognizerOnSpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs speechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("RecognizerOnSpeechRecognitionRejected: " + speechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs.Result.Text);
        }

        private void RecognizerOnSpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs speechHypothesizedEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hypothesized: " + speechHypothesizedEventArgs.Result.Text);
            tb.Text = speechHypothesizedEventArgs.Result.Text;
        }

        private void RecognizerOnSpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Detected position: " + e.AudioPosition);
        }

        private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
            tb.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip... I really don´t know how to solve this. I guess it´s not being installed correctly oO

Comment: Running the code "System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()" it returns me 0 installed recognizers. Sounds that it´s incompatible with win8..

Comment: If you look at the [docs for LoadGrammar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammar(v=vs.110).aspx) - they initialize `SpeechRecognitionEngine` like this: `new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))`. Perhaps that culture info is crucial here to be able to find recognizers?

Comment: It seems like would be very important if your system language was say Mandarin and the Speech SDK would only provide recognizers for American English and perhaps some other languages but not for Mandarin.

Comment: I just don´t know how to install this package. I downloaded from microsoft website but the installation closes for no reason before completition.. oO

Comment: [This one?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121)? I just installed it with no problems it seems. Perhaps you already have it installed and would have to uninstall first? Can you check for details on errors in eventvwr.exe or in some log files in your %TMP% folder?

Comment: I uninstalled and installed again.. no errors! =) ...but the same exception when I try to load a grammar /=

Comment: It didn´t work for me either... I tryied to install sdk 8.1 on win8 and sdk11 and runtime on winserver2012... same error.. omg whats going on hahahaa...thank you very much for your help Filip!

Comment: System.Speech vs. Microsoft.Speech?

Comment: System.Speech actually... Microsoft.Speech doesn´t appear to be added oO

Comment: I saw you can add Microsoft.Speech from here if you install the SDK11 thingy: "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Assembly\Microsoft.Speech.dll"

Comment: IT´S ALIIIIIIIIIIIIIVE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! OMG Don´t know how to thank you! Man.. you saved my life xD thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: Cool! You inspired me to write a minion app that will call me "Master" when I talk to it... :D

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAH sounds great!